# Office 365 and Excel

Tags: excel, windows

So, novice here. I have a program that was developed in Visual studio. The basic function, is to pull information from a few databases, and provide a list to pick options from, to export as an Excel file, with a list. It has a "template" Excel file with relevant formatting and info, which it copies initially, and then writes to that copy. It utilizes shared files on the network, and  saves this new file to the network. Previously, it functioned fairly well, but now, our office has transitioned to a more current version of Windows 10 and 7, and along the way we also picked up Office 365, and are now current on that. Problem is, when the program grabs the Excel files now, it keeps throwing up the error that the file is locked for editing, and won't allow it to overwrite or access the file. Only changes from it working was the updated Office 365. I originally thought it was OS related, but it's happening to both 7 and 10 users. And I also had it running on a computer that did not have the current Office update, without error, and once it updated overnight to the current Office, it broke. Did something in Excel change that would cause a conflict with this? Is there a line I can possibly add to bypass this issue? I've tried readonly=False, notify=false, ignorereadyonlyrecommended=true, I've tried adding a thread.sleep(500) in case there was a lag between the lock file updating on the server. Maybe I'm just missing an obvious solution.

Update:

```
Dim ExcelApp As New Excel.Application 'create new excel application
        ***Dim ExcelWkBk = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, [ReadOnly]:=False, Notify:=False) 'open the unitfile***
        Try
            Dim ExcelSheet As Excel.Worksheet = ExcelWkBk.Sheets("Distributor") 'open the distributor sheet
            ExcelApp.Visible = False 'make the application invisible
            ExcelApp.DisplayAlerts = False 'don't display any alerts, this operation is meant to silent to the user
            ExcelApp.ScreenUpdating = False 'this slows down the process so I turned off updates
            ExcelSheet.Range("A" & columnRow, "P" & aftAdjRow - 1).Name = "Unit" 'specifies the region which is the unit data
            ExcelSheet.Range("G" & titleRow + 1, "K" & aftAdjRow).Value2 = ExcelSheet.Range("G" & titleRow + 1, "K" & aftAdjRow).Value2 'refreshes the unit number values
            ExcelSheet.Range("G" & columnRow + 1, "G" & aftAdjRow).NumberFormat = "0"
            ExcelSheet.Range("I" & columnRow + 1, "K" & aftAdjRow).NumberFormat = "$#,##0;$-#,##0;$0;" 'custom format for the prices
            ExcelSheet.Rows(columnRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'hide column and config rows
            'ExcelSheet.Rows(configRow).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            'ExcelSheet.Rows(configRow + 1).EntireRow.Hidden = True
            ExcelSheet.Columns("E").EntireColumn.WrapText = True
            ExcelSheet.Range("I" & titleRow, "K" & titleRow).HorizontalAlignment = Excel.XlHAlign.xlHAlignCenter 'center prices column
            ExcelSheet.Range("Unit").VerticalAlignment = Excel.XlVAlign.xlVAlignTop 'change alignment
            ExcelSheet.Range("A" & columnRow, "P" & distRowCnt + 8).Font.Name = "Courier New" 'change font
            ExcelSheet.Range("A" & columnRow, "P" & distRowCnt + 9).Font.Size = 10

Dim ExcelWkBk = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, [ReadOnly]:=False, Notify:=False) 'open the unitfile - Is where it flags the error

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: ''testing1.xls' cannot be accessed. The file may be corrupted, located on a server that is not responding, or read-only.'
```

If I attempt to save a new file, overwrite an existing file, or open an existing file, it behaves as if the file is locked for editing or read only, even if there is no reason for it to be locked or open.

Comment: Can you share the rest of your code, or check the line by line to see where it hits the error?

Comment: Dim ExcelWkBk = ExcelApp.Workbooks.Open(filepath, [ReadOnly]:=False, Notify:=False)

Comment: Is where it flags when it breaks

Comment: Where is this code running, and how is it triggered?

Comment: Can you add these details to the original question as well?

Comment: Taking this code fragment at face value,  you are opening the file _twice_.  And it's the second one that fails.  Really,  what else did you expect?

Comment: Where is it opening the file twice? I am not the author of the code, so I'm not fully familiar with where it would be a double instance.

Comment: I think the way you've posted the code doesn't make a clear distinction between the code and the error description: it looks like you're running the `Open` line twice...  It's possible your Excel object crashed and is still running as a process, with a lock on the file you're trying to open.